# Constructing a Darboux basis for a real, skew-symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Suppose I have a skew-symmetric, real $4\times4$ matrix $M$. This implies that all its eigenvalues are imaginary and come in pairs. Let us call them $\pm i \lambda_1$ and $\pm i \lambda_2$ with $\lambda_1, \lambda_2 \in \mathbb{R}$ and let us call the corresponding eigenvectors $v^\pm_1$ and $v^\pm_2$ such that $M v^-_2= -i\lambda_2 v^-_2$, and so on.

Using these four eigenvectors one can construct the matrix $S = (v^+_1, v^-_1, v^+_2, v^-_2)$ such that $J = S^{-1}MS = \text{diag}( i\lambda_1, -i\lambda_1, i\lambda_2, -i\lambda_2 )$ is the diagonalized matrix. So far so good.

I seem to recall that under some additional circumstances (i.e. $\text{rank}M = 4$?) one can find a special orthogonal matrix $R \in SO(4)$ such that

$D = R^T M R = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & i\lambda_1 & 0 & 0 \\ -i\lambda_1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & i\lambda_2 \\ 0 & 0 & -i\lambda_2 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$.

//edit: The matrix should be brought to the form

$D = R^T M R = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & \lambda_1 & 0 & 0 \\ \lambda_1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \lambda_2 \\ 0 & 0 & \lambda_2 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$.

My question: how do I construct this matrix $R$ from the four eigenvectors $v^\pm_{1,2}$ that I already know? This basis is sometimes called a Darboux basis I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the eigenvalues of your $D$ are $\pm\lambda_1$ and $\pm\lambda_2$, so it cannot be orthogonally similar to $M$.

You have 
$$
\begin{bmatrix}1/\sqrt2&-1/\sqrt2\\ 1/\sqrt2&1/\sqrt2\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\ 0&-1\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}1/\sqrt2&1/\sqrt2\\ -1/\sqrt2&1/\sqrt2\end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}
0&1\\ 1&0
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
So, with 
$$
L=\begin{bmatrix}1/\sqrt2&1/\sqrt2&0&0\\ -1/\sqrt2&1/\sqrt2&0&0\\
0&0&1/\sqrt2&1/\sqrt2\\0&0& -1/\sqrt2&1/\sqrt2
\end{bmatrix},
$$
you get 
$$
L^TJL=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & i\lambda_1 & 0 & 0 \\ i\lambda_1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & i\lambda_2 \\ 0 & 0 & i\lambda_2 & 0 \end{bmatrix}.$$
Thus $R=SL$ seems to be what you are looking for.

Comment: I fixed my typo above, there are no imaginary units in the matrix in the Darboux frame. The SO(4) matrix you gave me is some kind of a double rotation by Pi/4, isn't it?

Comment: What you are describing is the $4\times 4$ special case of "symplectic diagonalization" of $2n\times 2n$ antisymmetric matrices.  Traditional diagonalization is done with the Gram-Schmidt process, and there is a [symplectic version of Gram-Schmidt](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4376585/symplectic-version-of-gram-schmidt).

Comment: The reason you have a double $\pi/4$ rotation is that you are taking each pair of complex conjugate eigenvalue pairs $i\lambda_i$ and $-i\lambda_i$ in the diagonalized form and rotating them in the 2-dimensional eigenspace to get a real-valued $2 \times 2$ matrix block, just as you can rotate the complex matrix $\{\{i,0\},\{0,-i\}\}$ to get the (real) symplectic form $\{\{0,1\},\{-1,0\}\}$. This way you get a real-valued matrix while preserving most of the diagonal-ness.