# Symplectic version of "Gram-Schmidt"

Tags: linear-algebra, symplectic-linear-algebra, gram-schmidt

Let $w$ be a symplectic form on a vector space $V$ of dimension $2g$. Suppose we already have a free family $(a_1, \dots, a_g)$ such that $w(a_i, a_j) = 0$. I also have a family $(b_1, \dots, b_g)$ which verify that $(a_1, \dots, a_g, b_1, \dots, b_g)$ is a basis of $V$. I've read somewhere that there is a symplectic version of Gram-Schmidt to make the basis $(a_1, \dots, a_g, b_1, \dots, b_g)$ a symplectic one, but concretely, how does it work ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Wikipedia cites](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symplectic_basis) Ana Cannas da Silva's *Lectures on Symplectic Geometry* for its assertion of this fact.  Prof. da Silva has kindly made a [pdf copy](https://people.math.ethz.ch/%7Eacannas/Papers/lsg.pdf) of these lecture notes available from her staff page at ETH Zurich's web site.  The procedure you're looking for appears to be described in the proof of Theorem $1.1$ on pages $3–4$.

Comment: Indeed. Also, regarding google-able keywords, "geometric algebra" (e.g., E. Artin's old book by that name) is a somewhat larger body of info that discusses such things.

Comment: Thank you very much to both of you !